# Хороший аналог Admob в России

Tags: java, android, admob, встроенная-реклама

Работал с Admob, все было хорошо, но ограничили показ т.к. контент приложения связан с азартными играми(хоть и косвенно).

Можете предложить замену Admob с которым вы работали и в котором нормальные условия?

Или может посоветуете медиатор с которым работаете?..

Comment: MyTarget русские вроде

Comment: Вы пробовали работать с ними?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [Smaato](https://www.smaato.com/) - работал с ним в эпоху, когда Play Market не позволял выставлять платные приложения, а AdMob'а еще и не было в помине.

Тогда позволял выводить денежки только на PayPal, сейчас не знаю.